# MVC: Controller keeps array of model objects or view objects?

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller, conceptual

I have a view controller `placeViewController` which pulls in a bunch of `Place` objects, and from these loads and populates a matching bunch of `PlaceView` objects which are then displayed as subviews to its main view.

I need to update these views periodically which requires information from the model and other places to be pushed into the views

How should I properly structure this?

- Keep an array of `Place` objects and give the model a `PlaceView` property to store pointers to the views
- Keep an array of `PlaceView` objects and give the view a `Place` property to store pointers to the places
- Keep both arrays and use a lot of `indexOfObject` `objectAtIndex` to jump between them
- Some other way??

Comment: I would create a `NSMutableArray` with `PlaceView` objects. And the `PlaceView` class holds a `@property Place *place`

Comment: basvk, I think this is the best approach and it is what i ended up doing. If you want to post as an answer I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well basvk got the answer in his comment but hasn't posted an actual answer for me to mark correct.

So here it is: "I would create a `NSMutableArray` with `PlaceView` objects. And the `PlaceView` class holds a `@property Place *place`"

Answer (score 0):

> I need to update these views periodically which requires information
>   from the model and other places to be pushed into the views

You should really focus on an ObserverPattern. Yours views register to "notifications", and when changes are made, your registered views are notified.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

You still can use NSNotificationCenter, but it will not futfill your needs since you need yours views make update per Place object (paired like a dictionary). So i recommend you to implement your own.
It will loose coupled because your controller will just  only make glue between the observer and your views, and all the "logic" will be handled by the observer.